# Fork process: Resume parent process while children terminated (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I've written a C++ application that waits until an event occurs (e.g. wait for incoming connection). After that event occured, it will continue by forking a child process that handles that event.

So, my code looks essentially like this:

```
int main(void) {
  while(1) {
    Event e = waitUntilSomethingHappens(); // blocks execution until event occurs
    pid_t pid = fork(); 
    if (pid == 0) {
      doChildStuff(e); 
      exit(0); 
      return 0; 
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My expectation now was that the child process will terminate (because of `exit(0)` and/or `return`). Indeed, it leaves the while loop, but it seems not to be terminated. When I hit `ps -e`, both processes are displayed, whereas the child process is marked as `<defunct>`.

Why doesn't it disappear? What can I do to let it disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use one of the [`wait` calls](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) to get a notification for the state change of the child.

From the manual:

> A child that terminates, but has not been waited for becomes a
>   "zombie". The kernel maintains a minimal set of information about the
>   zombie process (PID, termination status, resource usage information)
>   in order to allow the parent to later perform a wait to obtain
>   information about the child. As long as a zombie is not removed from
>   the system via a wait, it will consume a slot in the kernel process
>   table, and if this table fills, it will not be possible to create
>   further processes. If a parent process terminates, then its "zombie"
>   children (if any) are adopted by init(8), which automatically performs
>   a wait to remove the zombies.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. But the question is now, where do I have to put the `wait` call? I don't want to block my parent process with `wait`. It should wait for new events while the child is executing. 

I could collect all pids in a `std::vector` and when it exeeds a certain size, I can wait for all pids to terminate. Is there a better solution?

Or could I delegate the waiting task to another child?

Comment: Depends on the use case. But in any case, from the manual: `WNOHANG` - return immediately if no child has exited.